# Create Sh and Bin File to Execute all SQL Scripts in folder

Tags: batch-file, sh

I'm not sure if this is possible, but if I have a directory with 40+ SQL Scripts in it. Is it possible to make a run_scripts.bat and/or a run_scripts.sh file to execute all SQL scripts in the folder? Sorry I don't have even a start code, but I've been looking around at how this would be done to no avail. Thanks to anyone that can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the database you use (e.g. mysql), you can just run in a loop:

```
for f; do
    mysql -u $DBUSER -p $DB <$f
done
```

Then, you can call this on the command line:

```
$ sh run_scripts.sh *.sql
```

Comment: Alright, so say I have my variables as such. `code`$DBUSER=register; DB=website; for f; do mysql -u $DBUSER -p $DB <$f done `code` Any idea what I'm doing wrong there? :(

Comment: What's the output of the script?

Comment: Access denied for user -p @ localhost using password no

Comment: Got Past that. Now it asks me for the password for every query. Is there any way to fix that part? =/

Comment: And by the way. I was getting the error because I had set my variables like I was using PHP without realizing it.

Comment: Now the last part I'm trying to get setup is something along the lines of having a password variable and having the script `code` for f; do mysql -u $DBUSER -p $PASS $DB <$f done `code` I had tried `code` -p $PASS '$DB' `code` in the hopes that it would work to no avail.

Comment: You can either give the password on the command line `-p$PASS` (no space in between!), but then everybody can see it. Better yet, put it in an options file `$HOME/.my.cnf`

Comment: Awesome. Appreciate it. :) I'm new to using Ubuntu for development, so I'll have to look into what all I can do, but I've never seen the $HOME variable. Is that user defined or is that Global? Sorry; off topic I know, but still good to know and it's all working now. Thanks a ton.

Comment: $HOME holds your home directory, `/home/morgan` for example. It is set, when you login to the system. If you're interested, look into http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info. There you have links to shell scripting tutorials.